# python append (+=) replaces entire string with last char

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script to print out the unique characters in a given string.

Each unique character is appended to output, however at the end, only the last character appended is printed.

```
input = "1234a4321b1234c4321d" 

output= ""

for x in input:
    if x not in output:
        output += x

print x
```

I expect this to print: 1234abcd

but it only prints is: d

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be printing `output`. `x` will always be last character after the loop finishes

Comment: BTW you can do the same thing using a one liner `''.join(set(input))`

Comment: will that retain their order as well?

Comment: Why doesn't your expected output include `1234`? You only want the characters that appear exactly once in the input? Then you have to count the repetitions of each character, and at the end print the ones with 1 repetition.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the question per your comment.

Comment: @ash Good catch! sets are unordered so the order won't be retained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should print `output`, not `x`.

Also, note that your method will not print only the unique characters, as each letter will be added the first time it appears. (When `1` first checked, it is not in `output` yet ... )

Comment: sweet zombie jesus! I cant believe I did that... I need a nap. Thank you, good sir!

Comment: Why isn't that the unique characters? Each character is printed only the first time it appears, the repetitions are not printed.

Comment: @Barmar - see the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to print `output` and not `x`

```
>>> input = "1234a4321b1234c4321d" 
>>> output = ""
>>> for x in input:
...     if x not in output:
...             output += x
... 
>>> print output
1234abcd
>>>
```

but that not what you are after either. Atleast if you expect your output to be acbd as you alluded to in your original question.

so, perhaps you want check for digits

```
>>> output = ""
>>> for x in input:
...     if x.isdigit() == False:
...             output += x
... 
>>> output
'abcd'
```

alternatively if you want only unique items you may want a `set()`

```
>>> output = ''.join(set((i for i in input)))
>>> output
'acbd1324'
```

finally, a more succinct way of doing what you were originally after

```
>>> output = ''.join(set((i for i in input if i.isdigit() == False)))
>>> output
'acbd'
```

lastly, @RedBaron offers an even easier way in his comments to the original question

`output = ''.join(set(input))`

Comment: You should remove the `[`,`]` square brackets from the `set` constructor to have a generator expression instead of a list comp.